Give an example of a noncommutative domain in which non-trivial two-sided ideals are principal (cyclic).
A domain $R$ is called the principal left (resp. right) ideal domain if all left (resp. right) ideals of $R$ are cyclic (principal). There are some rings that are a principal left ideal domain but not a principal right ideal domain. Also, there are non-commutative rings that are both principal left and right ideal domains, I mean a domain $R$ is non-commutative such that every right ideal of $R$ is principal as well as every left ideal of $R$ (e.g., $R=D[x,\sigma, \delta]$, Ore extension, where $\sigma$ is an automorphism and $D$ is a division ring).
Here arises a question:
Is there a non-commutative non-simple domain $R$ such that all two-sided ideals of $R$ are principal but some left and right ideals of $D$ are not?

Are you not satisfied by the direct sum of two simple algebras, such that one of them has a non-principal left/right ideal?

@xsnl Thank you for your contribution. However, please note that $R$ is a domain, and, the product of two simple algebras is not a domain.
